# PHPMailer not sending attachment

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

Trying to use PHPMailer to send an attachment, the body is sent but the attachment is not. Here is the code:

```
$filename2 = "$key.txt";
$filename = "$key.zip";
$file_path = dirname(__FILE__);
$myfile = fopen("$file_path/$filename2", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $privkey);
fwrite($myfile, $pubkey);
fclose($myfile);
$zipFile = "$file_path/$filename";
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)){
    die("Failed to create archive\n");
}


$zipArchive->addGlob($filename2);
if (!$zipArchive->status == ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OK){
    echo "Failed to write local files to zip\n";
}

$zipArchive->close();

//Create Email to send to user with atachment
$message = "Test Email";
$subject = "Testing emails with attachment";

try
{
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->setFrom('register@gasp.grn.cc', 'Gasp Bot');
$email->addReplyTo('no-reply@gasp.grn.cc', 'No-Reply');
$email->Subject   = $subject;
$email->Body      = $message;
$email->AddAddress($to,$username);
$email->AddAttachment($file_path, $filename);
$email->Send();
echo "Message has been sent";
}
catch(phpmailerException $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
unlink ($zipFile);
unlink ("$file_path/$filename2");
```

I already tried

```
 $email->AddAttachment($zipFile);
```

but if I use this the body of the message is also not sent.

Can somebody show me the error I'm making?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: How did you configured mailer?
Ex:- `$email->isSMTP();`

Comment: You can try adding a `try/catch` as per this example https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/AdvancedMail

Comment: @DinukaDayarathna is that needed??, i saw a lot of code without it so i assumed it could be used without an smtp

Comment: @Fred-ii- no errors displayed using the  `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- adding a `try-catch` didn't do anything

Comment: `if(!$email->Send()){
echo "Message was not sent <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $email->ErrorInfo;
exit;`
Your code has a error not showing the error. You may have taken it from GitHub :)
Replace the code with above since your object is `$email`
It will display the error.

Comment: @DinukaDayarathna didnt see that :P thanks :D, but that doesnt change anything :'(

Comment: OK.
Does it shows `Message has been sent`?

Comment: yes, and the message is sent, the problem is that the attachment is not sent in the message @DinukaDayarathna

Comment: According to your code If mail sent the error msg won't show. You have to go to `try{} catch{}` to catch the error of attaching the file.
Please refer [link] (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for more

Comment: @DinukaDayarathna updated the code up there with the catch's i'm using, doesnt detect anything

Comment: @NobodyNemo I edited it. Pls refer. There were some mistakes.

Comment: i was actualy using the try catch like that it was just writing here that i didnt right correctly :/ still it doesnt show any error the only output is `Message sent` @DinukaDayarathna

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100389/discussion-between-dinuka-dayarathna-and-nobodynemo).

Comment: You need to check your return values. Don't just assume it's worked.

Comment: @Synchro it doenst return any error and it sends the email with the attachments i tested like 8 times already

Comment: Check the return value *of `addAttachment`*, not just `send`. Your code is not doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Code

```
$filename2 = "$key.txt";
$filename = "$key.zip";
$file_path = dirname(__FILE__);
$myfile = fopen("$file_path/$filename2", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $privkey);
fwrite($myfile, $pubkey);
fclose($myfile);
$zipFile = "$file_path/$filename";
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)){
     die("Failed to create archive\n");
}


$zipArchive->addGlob($filename2);
if (!$zipArchive->status == ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OK){
   echo "Failed to write local files to zip\n";
}

$zipArchive->close();
try{
 //Create Email to send to user with atachment
 $message = "TEST MESSAGE";
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->setFrom('register@gasp.grn.cc', 'Gasp Bot');
$email->addReplyTo('no-reply@gasp.grn.cc', 'No-Reply');
$email->Subject   = $subject;
$email->IsHTML(true);
$email->Body      = $message;
$email->AddAddress($to,$username);
$email->AddAttachment("$file_path/$filename");
if(!$email->Send()){
   echo "Message was not sent <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $email->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}else{
   echo "Message has been sent";
}
}catch(phpmailerException $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
unlink ($zipFile);
unlink ("$file_path/$filename2");
```

aperantly adding

```
$email->IsHTML(true);
```

made it so that

```
 $email->AddAttachment("$file_path/$filename");
```

works

Comment: `$email->isHTML(true);` worked neh? Happy to hear code works. :)